# Scroll View only displaying 1 image

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiscrollview

For my scrollView the images are downloaded from the web via DLImageLoader. The links to these images are reviewed from Firebase at first. 
When I run the app the scroll view only displays the first image and when I swipe it just shows a blank screen. I checked to see if the links are working by displaying each element of the array as text and that part is fine.

```
override func viewDidLoad()

{

    super.viewDidLoad()

    FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Main data").child("Home Image URLs").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapString = snapshot.value as? String {



       self.imageURLsVAR = snapString

            self.imageURLs = self.imageURLsVAR.components(separatedBy: ",")

  //     self.label.text = String(self.imageURLs[1])

      for i in 0..< imageURLs.count-1{
      let imageview = UIImageView()
   // imageview.image = homeImages[i]
      dlURL = String(imageURLs[i])


      DLImageLoader.sharedInstance().image(fromUrl: String(imageURLs[i]), imageView: imageview)
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageview.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.imgScrollView.frame.width, height: self.imgScrollView.frame.height)
        imgScrollView.contentSize.width = imgScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        imgScrollView.addSubview(imageview)
        view.sendSubview(toBack: imgScrollView)
    }
        }

}) { (error) in
    print(error.

localizedDescription)
    }


}
```

[Image links stored in array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKOGl.jpg)

"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/thedurbanapp-acc22.appspot.com/o/Home%20Images%2Fp1040565.jpg?alt=media&token=62632d2a-82d7-4448-b99c-455383872703"

Comment: you are not setting the image for image view . if you set that i wt will work

Comment: can give you log of image url's your are getting . am asking `self.imageURLs`

Comment: I edited the question and added an image of the links as well as 1 link, it won't allow me to post 2 or more links @Vinodh

Comment: Any idea what it could be and what else I can try? @Vinodh

Comment: get correct url from firebase

Answer (score 0):

The reason is url not properly formatted . when i try to load the link you pasted here it works fine . But other url not working properly . check the valid path . And one more thing one first url in `imageURLs` is a valid url others are not valid . Check they are opening in browser and then try loading in image .

can you try the below code

```
        let imageURL = imageURLs[i].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

  DLImageLoader.sharedInstance().image(fromUrl: String(imageURL), imageView: imageview)
```

Comment: It didn't make a difference @Vinodh